# Bundle is waiting for namespace handlers [http://dozer.sourceforge.net] in JBoss Fuse 6.2.1

Tags: xml, apache-camel, jbossfuse, dozer

I am trying to use camel-dozer component (JBoss Fuse 6.2.1) . when I deployed my bundle on Karaf it's giving me the error as "Bundle loader-dozer-decoder/3.0.0 is waiting for namespace handlers [http://dozer.sourceforge.net]" and bundle is in Grace period.

Can someone please help me.

and my mapping file looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd"> 

    <mapping>
```

Comment: Make sure that you have installed the `camel-dozer` feature. `features:install camel-dozer`

Comment: i did install camel-dozer JBossFuse:karaf@root> list|grep camel-dozer
[ 287] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-dozer (2.15.1.redhat-621166)
JBossFuse:karaf@root>